# sorting by lowest key in a dict (Python)

Tags: python, sorting

I have a dictionary:
where 0 and 1 are two index and the other numbers inside the two dictionaries are the frequency of each word in a previous list of strings

letter_positions={0: {'l': 1, 'y': 2, 'm': 1, 'r': 2}, 1: {'t': 2, 'e': 1, 'n': 1, 's': 3}}

I get that by a function that return a dictionary with the most frequent character of a string by index.

Now I'm using this function to get the most frequent character for each index:

```
final_dict = {}
for idx, counts in letter_positions.items():
    most_popular = max(counts.items(), key=lambda v: v[1])
    final_dict[idx] = most_popular[0][0]
```

The problem is that in the index 0 of the dictionary the most frequent characters are 'y' and 'r', my code return me 'y' in the final_dict dictionary, but I want to get the lowest alphabetic character 'r'.

How can I edit my code or what do I have to add here

```
    most_popular = max(counts.items(), key=lambda v: v[1])
```

to perform my need? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to sort the dictionary by the keys:

```
most_popular = max(sorted(counts.items()), key=lambda v: v[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to `min()` and change the `key=` function:

```py
letter_positions = {
    0: {"l": 1, "y": 2, "m": 1, "r": 2},
    1: {"t": 2, "e": 1, "n": 1, "s": 3},
}


final_dict = {}
for idx, counts in letter_positions.items():
    most_popular = min(counts.items(), key=lambda v: (-v[1], v[0]))
    final_dict[idx] = most_popular[0][0]

print(final_dict)
```

Prints:

```
{0: 'r', 1: 's'}
```

Answer (score 0):

When sorting, you can add a second metric in a `list` (or `tuple`), such that elements tied for the first position will be decided by the second value:

```
final_dict = {}
for idx, counts in letter_positions.items():
    most_popular = max(counts.items(), key=lambda v: [v[1],-ord(v[0])])
    final_dict[idx] = most_popular[0][0]
```

In the code above, we use `[v[1],-ord(v[0])]` as the new metric to sort values. `ord` returns an integer representing the position of each letter in the alphabet, so `ord(v[0])` will give a higher scores to letters at the beggining of the alphabet.

The output is now:

```
# final_dict = {0: 'r', 1: 's'}
```